# How to solve this? $a,b\in R, a+\ln{a}=2, \ln{(1-b)}=b+1$, show value of $a+b$.

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations

How to solve this? $a,b\in \Bbb R, a+\ln a=2, \ln (1-b)=b+1$, show value of $a+b$.
Notice that $\ln (1-b)+(1-b)=2$, we have $1-b=a$.
But I don't understand the reason to do this. Why do I have to change the form of the 2nd equation?  Is there any idea? Or other methods to calculate the sum of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Do you mean **solve**?

Comment: yes, i've corrected it :)

Comment: The idea is to show that $x + \ln x$ is a bijection, which is why we can conclude $1-b = a$. $\quad$ If we tried it for $ a + 1/a = (1-b) + 1/(1-b)$, then we cannot conclude that $ 1-b = a$.

Comment: Well $2 = \ln a+a$ and $2= \ln(1-b) +(1-b)$ so $\ln a + a = \ln (1-b)+(1-b)$.  Now notice that if $x > y$ then $\ln x > \ln y$ and so $\ln x + x > \ln y+y$.  So if $a > 1-b$ we'd have $\ln a + a > \ln(1-b)+(1-b)$. But that doesn't happen. And if $a < 1-b$ we'd have $\ln a + a > \ln(1-b) +(1-b)$ but that doesn't happen.  So the only option left is $a = 1-b$